# Negative Lookahead for word

Tags: regex

I have been banging my head against the wall on this one, I am fairly new to regex and am a bit out of my depth. I am working with this network compliance software that doesn't allow for matching multiple criteria in a field however does accept regular expressions.

```
!(?!.*FastEthernet[0-24].[0-24]\.[0-250])
```

The software parses all information until it matches the expressed criteria. So in my case I want it to match `!` unless it is followed by a sub interface `FastEthernet#/#.#` where # is any number.

Here is my data

```
interface FastEthernet0/0
shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet0/0.100
ip address 192.168.1.100
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
shutdown
!
```

Comment: Be very, very careful using `.*` in a regex.  `.*` matches everything.  `.*?` is safer, but even that is pretty dangerous.  Always try to make a regex that does not include `.*` if you can.

Comment: Do you want to match only the last `!` in your example?

Comment: My target is to match the second !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
!(?!\s*interface FastEthernet\d/\d\.\d)
```

See this running on [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/eKTumW7Klk)

Comment: @mart1n it allows `.` to match newline characters (which it wouldn't normally be allowed to), but it shouldn't be necessary in this particular case.

Comment: In that case, shouldn't your expression match an (optional) new line after the `!`? Also, you should probably escape the `.` and `/`.

Comment: @mart1n good call on the escape dot (fixed), but I think the optional newline is covered, because `\s` includes newlines.

Comment: I tested this and it did not seem to work, not sure if it is the software or your expression. Your expression matched all 3 lines

Comment: @anubhava OK. Since I've opted to not use dots, removed.

Comment: @Luky I have edited the answer to accommodate your `interface` word in your sample input. Note that in your input, only the middle line has digits that conform to `n/n.n` pattern

Comment: Thank you Bohemian, still not working but at this point I believe it is the vendor's software and not the syntax. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Luky: Learn to upvote the answers you accept. Just click the up arrow once.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky I am new to this, long time lurker first post. But thanks

Comment: @Luky: May the force be with you.

Answer (score 2):

I would use this:

```
!(?!(.|\n|\r)*FastEthernet\d\d?\/\d\d?\.\d{1,3})
```

It seems to [work for me](http://www.regex101.com/r/qM1tG3).

Comment: @Luky I removed the `(?s)`. Could you try this one?

Comment: Thank you for the help, however it seems to be a problem with the software so I can't identify whether it works.

Comment: @Luky Sounds like a terribad problem then :( I hope you get it sorted out soon!

Comment: Yeah luckily the developer is quick to reply